# Return id of associated object through pluck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model City which has many Listings. Listings have many Schools. I am trying to find all the school_ids in a city.

```
city.listings.joins(:schools).pluck(:name).uniq
```

returns the names of all the schools in the city as expected.

but

```
city.listings.joins(:schools).pluck(:id).uniq
```

returns the listing_ids for all listings in the city, not the ids of the schools.

How can I get the `school_ids`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
city.listings.joins(:schools).pluck('schools.id').uniq
```

will do it for you

**Reason**

```
city.listings.joins(:schools).pluck(:id)
```

yields query starting

```
select listings.id from listings inner join schools on .....
```

but

```
city.listings.joins(:schools).pluck('school.id')
```

gives query starting

```
select schools.id from listings inner join schools on .....
```

Comment: Once you start violating the abstraction ActiveRecord provides you end up on a slippery slope. Here you make the mistake of assuming `pluck` will inspect the content of the argument and pluralize it to match the table, but it inserts a string argument into the query unchanged. Since the table name is likely pluralized, this query will actually fail. If the `School` model uses another table entirely or if the `schools` relationship uses another model your queries are going to end up very confusing to work with.

Comment: oh yeah, its a mistake. edited the answer @coreyward

Answer (score 2):

You might find it easier to go the other way around:

```
School.where(listings: city.listings).pluck(:id)
```

And assuming you needed to do something based on those schools, you can avoid loading the IDs entirely and just continue to compose your query:

```
PerformanceReports
  .where(school: School.where(listings: city.listings))
  .order(score: :desc)
  .limit(5)
```

Comment: This will create three queries: one for the city, second for the listings, third for schools. I would avoid that.

Comment: @MichaelKosyk That's incorrect. The `city` is already an instance of a model (see original question). This will otherwise create a single query that uses a subquery (`School.where` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`).

Comment: I didn't know you could use objects in a where clause. I'd like to explore this more. I have an instance of the City model (city), and your code above resulted in this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: schools.listing: SELECT "schools"."id" FROM "schools" WHERE "schools"."listing" IN (SELECT "listings"."id" FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."city_id" = ?)`

Comment: @tomb Updated; I think you just need to pluralize `listing` to `listings`.